# Call an third-party API on Magento basic operations like Update Customer

Tags: api

I need to do calls to an Third-Party API when customer updates his account for example. I'll need another actions too, but I think if I understand that one I can try to do the other ones, like update credit card information etc...

Thanks and I appreciate this website and all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best (in my opinion) way to do this is to use event observers. For an introduction to event observers checkout these articles:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method,

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part11-series-eventsapi,

http://www.techflirt.com/magento-event-observer-hook-in-magento/.

This is the most complete list of Magento events, that i managed to find:

http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/.

Once you figure in which events you are interested, just make an API call inside your observer method.